# Heading of a XML 1.0/ RSS 2.0 document?

Tags: java, xml, sockets

Here are the XML/RSS Feed file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
                xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <channel>
  ...
    <item>
    ...
    </item>

    <item>
    ...
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

If I want to get the file with socket like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(/* THE SITE*/ , 80);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWritter osw = new OutputStreamWritter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferWriter(osw);
bw.write("HEADER OF THE SITE");
```

What header should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on what HTTP is and how it works.  Read [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either learn about HTTP or use a higer-level API like `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.